# Osm2pgsql crashed on import. Can I continue with what has been imported so far?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I recently imported the osm planet file using osm2pgsql. The process crashed (hung my whole box) when creating the geometry indices and other indices on the tables. Scouring through the source code, it looks fairly trivial to add the indices by hand, however I was wondering if anybody knew if the database is consistent at this point (ie, all row data comitted).

Don't want to have to start over with the whole import really.

Answer (score 1):

After the import of the raw data, osm2pgsql builds the polygon data out of closed ways and multipolygon relations. Building indices is the last step, so you might rescue the polygons.

I'm not sure at what stage the planet_osm_roads are generated from the planet_osm_lines. These are needed for low level zoom of roads and railways.

But I would not be sure that the table that was processed while crashing is consistent anymore.

You can try building the indices manually, and see if the data looks good by pre-rendering a small area. This will surely take less time than doing the whole import again.

Comment: Yea a response from the dev mailing list indicates the rows should be stable. fsync was off in pgsql but it got quite a long way in to indexing so it might be safe. Your suggestion is good. I'm trying to pull the indexing statements out of the source atm.